# Getting date from year/week/weekday in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

I am struggling to get the proper date from year/weeknumber/weekday in pandas. I can get it to work using `datetime` on strings but not in pandas

```
from datetime import datetime
y = 2019
w = 'Week 46'
d = 'Sun'
s = str(y)+'-'+str(w)+'-'+d
u = datetime.strptime(s, "%G-Week %V-%a")
v = datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-Week %W-%a")
```

`u` is giving me my desired output (2019-11-17)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [s], columns = ['Day'])
df[date] = pd.to_datetime(df['Day'], format="%Y-Week %W-%a")
```

gives me the same offset as `v` and I can't pass `format="%G-Week %V-%a"` as `%G` and `%V` are invalid.

Any thoughts on how to get dates as from `u`?

Comment: works for me as expected with pandas version 0.25.3 (2019-11-17 and 2019-11-24 respectively)

Comment: Do you get 2019-11-17 in df[date]?

Comment: Yes, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4JDH.png (sorry for the picture, but I can't format longer code text in a comment)

Comment: Aha, it was the pandas version that didn't support my date format. Upgraded and now it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using an older pandas version (0.24.2) and it didn't support the format `"%G%V%a"` in `pd.to_datetime`. An upgrade to 0.25.3 solved it.